# How to get country, region, town and area name for a user provided area_id migrates to user tables

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, relationship

I want to get the name of an area, a town, a region, and a country using the area_id which migrates to the user table that belongs to a particular user.

I have 5 tables which include,

> A Country table with id, name, and description.
>
> A Region table with id, name, description, and country_id
>
> A Town table with id, name, description, and region_id.
>
> An Area table with id, name, description, and town_id.
>
> and I have a user table which the value of the area_id  migrates to the user table and have attributes id, name, surname, email, phone, area_id.

I wish to know how can I get the name of the area, town, region, and country for a particular user, provided the area_id exists in the user table in the database using Laravel.

In my user Controller, I did something like this

```
 /**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

public function accueil(Session $session)
{
    $recentJobbers =User::with('Area')
        ->limit(5)
         ->whereType('jobber')
        ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
        ->get();

    return view('home', compact('recentJobbers','areas', 'categories'));
}
```

and in part of my blade view I did this

```
 <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="heading">
                        <h2>Jobbeurs en vedette</h2>
                        <span>Principaux jobbers ayant déjà  été solicités pour leur travail.</span>
                    </div><!-- Heading -->
                    <div class="job-listings-sec">

                        @foreach($recentJobbers as $recentJobber)
                        <div class="job-listing">
                            <div class="job-title-sec">
                                <div class="c-logo"> <img src="{{url('images/avatars/'. $recentJobber->photo) }}" alt="Image" /> </div>
                                <h3><a href="{{ route('profileDetails', ['id'=>$recentJobber->id]) }}" title="">{{ $recentJobber->name }} {{ $recentJobber->surname }} <span style="float:right; padding-left: 10px;">(a ete contacte 25 fois)</span></a></h3>
                                <span>{{ $recentJobber->title }}</span>
                            </div>
                            <span class="job-lctn"><i class="la la-map-marker"></i>{{ $recentJobber->area->name }}, {{ $recentJobber->town->name }}, {{ $recentJobber->region->name }}</span>
                            <span class="fav-job"><i class="la la-heart-o"></i></span>
                            <a href="{{ route('profileDetails', ['id'=>$recentJobber->id]) }}" class="job-is ft">Voir Profil</a>
                        </div><!-- Job -->
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and in my user model, I did something like this

```
  public function category() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}

public function service() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Service');
}

 public function region() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Region');
}

public function town() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Town');
}

 public function area() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Area');
}
```

But it only returns the area name. Does not return the town, region nor country name.

I wish to know what is the easiest way to achieve this. Any help will be welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is to set up relationships on each model - not all of them on the `User`

```
class Region extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['country_id', 'name', 'description'];

    public function country(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
    }
}

class Town extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['region_id', 'name', 'description'];

    public function region(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Region::class);
    }
}

class Area extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['town_id', 'name', 'description'];

    public function town(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Town::class);
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // ...

    public function area(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Area::class);
    }
}
```

Then to get all those relationships you can use eager loading like so:

```
$recentJobbers = User::with('area.town.region.country')
        ->limit(5)
        ->whereType('jobber')
        ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Now you can access these on each record in the following way:

```
$recentJobber->area->town->region->country->name;
$recentJobber->area->town->region->name;
$recentJobber->area->town->name;
$recentJobber->area->name;
```

Make sure you use eager loading as shown above - otherwise fetching these relation on each iteration would be quite costly. Here's some additional info on the topic: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

To make it look a bit nicer, you could add accessors to your `User` model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // ...

    public function area(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Area::class);
    }

    public function getTownAttribute(): Town
    {
        return $this->area->town;
    }

    public function getRegionAttribute(): Region
    {
        return $this->area->town->region;
    }

    public function getCountryAttribute(): Country
    {
        return $this->area->town->region->country;
    }
}
```

and then call it like like in your view example

```
$recentJobber->country->name;
$recentJobber->region->name;
$recentJobber->town->name;
$recentJobber->area->name;
```

Here's a test to support the above

```
 /**
 * @test
 */
public function pulls_area_town_region_and_country()
{
    $country = Country::create([
        'name' => 'United Kingdom',
        'description' => 'United Kingdom'
    ]);

    $region = Region::create([
        'country_id' => $country->id,
        'name' => 'Somerset',
        'description' => 'Somerset'
    ]);

    $town = Town::create([
        'region_id' => $region->id,
        'name' => 'Bristol',
        'description' => 'Bristol'
    ]);

    $area = Area::create([
        'town_id' => $town->id,
        'name' => 'South',
        'description' => 'South'
    ]);

    factory(User::class)->create([
        'area_id' => $area->id
    ]);


    $user = User::with('area.town.region.country')->first();

    $this->assertEquals('United Kingdom', $user->area->town->region->country->name);
    $this->assertEquals('Somerset', $user->area->town->region->name);
    $this->assertEquals('Bristol', $user->area->town->name);
    $this->assertEquals('South', $user->area->name);

    $this->assertEquals('United Kingdom', $user->country->name);
    $this->assertEquals('Somerset', $user->region->name);
    $this->assertEquals('Bristol', $user->town->name);
    $this->assertEquals('South', $user->area->name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. This code was so nice, easy, well explained and exactly what I was looking for. Don't know how much to thank you for this. You really saved my time with this. One last thing, what is this  area(): BelongsTo role in this code?

Comment: You're very welcome - glad I could help. It's return type declaration - it basically indicates what method returns - in this case it will be instance of the \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo - so please make sure you import these classes at the top of each model class definition use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo - alternatively you can just remove it. Here's the link to this feature http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations

Comment: Thanks so much, I have added it and it works very perfectly. Sorry for the disturb but I have another question quite similar. Can you please check it out ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944987/how-to-get-title-description-and-price-stored-in-a-pivot-table-between-users-an/49945954?noredirect=1#comment86911952_49945954

Comment: Just posted an answer to that other question.